# Using enum as property of Realm model ios objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, realm

Is it possible to use an Enum as a property for my model? I currently have a class like this:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, ListType) {
  ListTypeDay,
  ListTypeWeek,
  ListTypeMonth,
  ListTypeYear,
  ListTypeCustom
};

@interface ListItem : RLMObject;

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, assign) ListType itemType;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isFinish;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSTimeInterval targetTime;

@end

RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(ListItem)
```

Terminal output：

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Can't persist property 'itemType' with incompatible type. Add to ignoredPropertyNames: method to ignore.'

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't store custom types (enums included) in Realm. See [Supported Types](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#models) in the documentation.

> Realm supports the following property types: BOOL, bool, int, NSInteger, long, long long, float, double, NSString, NSDate, NSData, and NSNumber tagged with a specific type.

Comment: can you give a sample of code adding enums in objective c?

Comment: You can store the raw values of the enum in Realm and then create the enum instance again from the raw values. Sadly I haven't written any Obj C for quite a while, but if you still can't figure this out, I can give you a sample code in Swift.

Comment: thanks for concern, but i can write it in swift.., but actually facing some problem in objective c...
https://stackoverflow.com/q/44496642/6402959

Comment: That error you are getting is quite clear and is the same as what my answer states. You are still trying to store enum types in Realm, which is not supported at the moment.

Comment: but isn't the enum type is NSInteger ?

Comment: The type of the rawValue is NSInteger. But the type of the enum is `enum YourEnumName`. Enum is not a primitive type, so if you create an enum, you will create a new type for it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace NSUInteger to NSInteger in type definition.

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, ListType)
```