# How to add enums to realm model? RLMObject?

Tags: ios, objective-c, enums, crash, realm

This is my serviceModel.h

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, OKServiceType) {
    OKServiceTypePending = 0,
    OKServiceTypeAccepted ,
    OKServiceTypeStarted,
    OKServiceTypeCompleted,
    OKServiceTypeClosed,
    OKServiceTypeCancelled
};
@interface serviceModel : RLMObject
@property NSString *job_id;
@property NSString *job_service_id;
@property NSString *service_id;
@property NSString *vendor_id;
@property NSString *timeslot;
@property NSString *points;
@property OKServiceType *status;
@property NSString *service_name;
@property NSString *image_url;
@property NSString *vendor_name;
@property NSString *subservice_desc;
@property NSString *subservice_id;
@property NSString *display_datetime;
@property NSString *status_text;
@end

RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(serviceModel)
```

I know we can add the property type as [These](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#models). But I cann;t find the proper way to add the enum to my models as realm collects all models on start only so it do crash due to this

```
@property OKServiceType *status;
```

I am having crash as

> Error      Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3010 "remote notifications are not supported in the simulator"
>
> UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=remote notifications are not
>   supported in the simulator} 2017-06-12 15:20:41.049 AppName[9974:157085]
>
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Can't persist property 'status' with incompatible type. Add to
>   ignoredPropertyNames: method to ignore.'

Any Help would be appreciated alot..

Comment: Just remove the pointer from your property name on the model: `@property OKServiceType status;` This should do it.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want to store your property as an `NSInteger` which is a supported type and create a method which returns your integer value as an enum of type `OKServiceType`.

```
@property NSInteger statusInt;

- (OKServiceType)status {
    return (OKServiceType)statusInt
}

- (void)setStatus(OKServiceType)status {
    self.statusInt = status
}
```

Comment: but isn't the added enum is of type nsinteger which is a supported type i guess..

Comment: Thats exactly what I thought when I had the same problem. But the property check in realm doesn't get this at the moment, so this would be a small workaround to use enums anyway.

Comment: its giving the enum check in swift but.. :(

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to set the enum property as (readonly). Read-only properties are automatically ignored by Realm and you can then use a custom setter. For example:

```
@property (readonly) OKServiceType *status;
@property NSInteger statusInt;

@implementation ServiceModel

- (OKServiceType)status {
    return (OKServiceType)_statusInt;
}

@end
```